# WI-FI connects and disconnect randomly

Tags: wireless-networking, router, lenovo-laptop

I am using a Lenovo Z460. I have Wi-Fi throughout my home.
I have 2 laptops and 3 mobile phones which use Wi-Fi
My Lenovo Laptop has problems connecting to Wi-Fi.
I can connect to Wi-Fi from my phones and my other laptop.
I had updated the WLAN Driver. However, it didn't help.

What can I do to resolve internet connection?

Comment: See [12 Tips for Troubleshooting Your Internet Connection](http://www.pcmag.com/slideshow/story/262550/12-tips-for-troubleshooting-your-internet-connection) and  
[How to Fix Your Wi-Fi Network: 7 Tips](http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the below troubleshooting steps and check the outcome.

1. Press Ctrl+R > type ncpa.cpl > select your Wireless Adapter > right click and try 'Disable' and 'Enable'
2. Try Disconnect and Connect
3. Go to Start > Computer > right click > Manage > on the right pane, select the Wireless Network adapter > right click and choose 'Uninstall'. Once the Uninstall finished, click on Search for New hardware changes. This will install the wireless adapter again.
4. Verify the 'SSID' and the 'Security Key'

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please explain the 3rd step